# How to plot Date in X Axis, Time in Y axis with Pandas/Matplotlib and present time in HH:MM format as tick labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have date in one column and time in another which I retrieved from database through pandas read_sql. The dataframe looks like below (there are 30 -40 rows in my daaframe). I want to plot them in a time series graph. If I want I should be in a position to convert that to Histogram as well.

```
    COB          CALV14
1  2019-10-04    07:04
2  2019-10-04    05:03
3  2019-10-03    16:03
4  2019-10-03    05:15
```

First I got different errors - like not numeric field to plot etc. After searching a lot,the closest post I could find is : [Matplotlib date on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958811/matplotlib-date-on-y-axis)

I followed and got some result - However the problem is:

> I have to follow number of steps (convert to str then list and then to matplot lib datetime format) before I can plot them. (Please refer the code I am using) There must be a smarter and more precise way to do this.
>   This does not show the time beside the axis the way they exactly appear in the data frame.  (eg it should show 07:03, 05:04 etc)

New to python - will appreciate any help on this.

**Code**

```
ob_frame['COB'] = ob_frame.COB.astype(str)
ob_frame['CALV14'] = ob_frame.CALV14.astype(str)
date = ob_frame.COB.tolist()
time = ob_frame.CALV14.tolist()
y = mdates.datestr2num(date)
x = mdates.datestr2num(time)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,9))
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.yaxis_date()
ax.xaxis_date()

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: u got output or any error coming ?

Comment: The format of the dates/times shown on the axis is completely independent of the format used inside the dataframe. See `matplotlib.dates` documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to it.I did not need to convert the data retrieved from DB to string type. Rest of the issue I was thought to be getting for not using the right formatting for the tick labels. Here goes the complete code - Posting in case this will help anyone.
In this code I have altered Y and X axis : i:e I plotted dates in x axis and time in Y axis as it looked better.

```
###### Import all the libraries and modules needed ######
import IN_OUT_SQL as IS ## IN_OUT_SQL.py is the file where the SQL is stored
import cx_Oracle as co
import numpy as np
import Credential as cd # Credentia.py is the File Where you store the DB credentials
import pandas as pd
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline

###### Connect to DB, make the dataframe and prepare the x and y values to be plotted ######

def extract_data(query):
    '''
    This function takes the given query as input, Connects to the Databse, executes the SQL and 
    returns the result in a dataframe. 
    '''
    cred = cd.POLN_CONSTR #POLN_CONSTR in the credential file stores the credential in '''USERNAME/PASSWORD@DB_NAME''' format
    conn = co.connect(cred)
    frame = pd.read_sql(query, con = conn)
    return frame

query = IS.OUT_SQL
ob_frame = extract_data(query)
ob_frame.dropna(inplace = True) # Drop the rows with NaN values for all the columns
x = mdates.datestr2num(ob_frame['COB'])  #COB is date in "01-MAR-2020" format- convert it to madates type
y = mdates.datestr2num(ob_frame['CALV14']) #CALV14 is time in "21:04"  Format- convert it to madates type


###### Make the Timeseries plot of delivery time in y axis vs delivery date in x axis ######
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
ax.clear() # Clear the axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'bo-', color = 'dodgerblue') #Plot the data
##Below two lines are to draw a horizontal line for 05 AM and 07 AM position
plt.axhline(y = mdates.date2num (pd.to_datetime('07:00')), color = 'red', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.75)
plt.axhline(y = mdates.date2num (pd.to_datetime('05:00')), color = 'green', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.75)
plt.xticks(x,rotation = '75')
ax.yaxis_date()
ax.xaxis_date()
#Below 6 lines are about setting the format with which I want my xor y ticks and their labels to be displayed
yfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M') 
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b-%y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yfmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))   # Every 1 Hour
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))   # Every 1 Day

####### Name the x,y labels, titles and beautify the plot #######
plt.style.use('bmh')
plt.xlabel('\nCOB Dates')
plt.ylabel('Time of Delivery (GMT/BST as applicable)\n')
plt.title(" Data readiness time against COBs (Last 3 months)\n")
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = "12" #Change the font 
# plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman" # Set the font type if needed
plt.tick_params(left = False, bottom = False, labelsize = 10) #Remove ticks, make tick labelsize 10
plt.box(False)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of `ob_frame['COB']` and `ob_frame['CALV14']` in your case? is it object? before you pass to `mdates.datestr2num()`?